# mozRequestFullScreen() not working properly in firefox 44.0.2

Tags: firefox, iframe

I am try mozRequestFullScreen() to do screen in full size in Mozilla. It works perfectly but the element present on video(Text, Button, etc) gets hide behind iframe. In older version of firefox it works and element display properly. But after firefox updated to 44.0.2 iframe is placed on top of element. And element gets hide.
Is there is any change in mozRequestFullScreen() after new version release.

Thanks in Advance.